# Duplicated svg image output TCPDF

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, extjs, tcpdf

I would like to export some charts made by ExtJs in PDF using TCPDF. I'm processing like that for passing html code to TCPDF:

```
var activeTabId = Ext.getCmp('tabs').activeTab.id
            , activeTab = Ext.getCmp('tabs').activeTab
            , svgHtml = '@<svg version="1.1" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
            , html=''
            , svg = $("#"+activeTabId+" svg")
            , svgArray=[];

        svg.each(function(){
            svgArray.push(svgHtml+svg.html()+'</svg>');
            html+= svgHtml+svg.html()+'</svg>';
        });

        svgJSON = JSON.stringify(svgArray);

        $.post('tcpdf/examples/example_058.php', { svg : svgJSON }, function(data){
            //window.location.href='tcpdf/examples/example_058.pdf';
            console.log(data);
        });
```

And then i'm using the examples 058 which draw svg image. Here's the code :

```
$svg = isset($_POST['svg'])?json_decode($_POST['svg']):NULL;
$yDepart = 30;
$svgHeight = 200;
echo '{ svgLength :'.count($svg).'}';
for($i=0;$i<count($svg);$i++){
    $pdf->AddPage('P', $page_format, false, false);
    $pdf->ImageSVG($svg[$i], $x=0, $y=$yDepart, $w=350.0, $h=400.0, $link='', $align='M', $palign='C', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);
}
```

The problem is that the Output PDF contains the same duplicated chart. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake :

Here's the problematic code :

```
svg.each(function(){
            svgArray.push(svgHtml+svg.html()+'</svg>');
            html+= svgHtml+svg.html()+'</svg>';
        });
```

I changed it by this one :

```
svg.each(function(){
    svgArray.push(svgHtml+$(this).html()+'</svg>');
    html+= svgHtml+$(this).html()+'</svg>';
});
```